# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: row column count mismatch

Tags: java, sql, hsqldb

I keep getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: row column count mismatch
```

But I have no idea why, it seems like the number of columns to rows match and the syntax is okay. Anyone have any idea what may be wrong? Thanks.

```
Insert into SomeTable
   (WPAPRJ_ID, COOPERATOR_NAME, FUNDING_TYPE, TOTAL_FUNDING_EST, MOD_TO_EXISTING_AGRMNT, 
    ORIGINAL_AGRMNT_NUMBER, RECUR_MULTI_YEAR, FS_POC, APPROVED_INDICATOR,
    REMARKS, STATUS, PROPOSAL_ID_NUMBER, ASSIGNED_SPECIALIST, 
    CREATED_DATE, CREATED_BY_ID, LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, LAST_MODIFIED_BY_ID, SENT_TO_IWEB)
 Values
   (12345, 'Test Cooperator Name', 'O', 99999, 'Y', 
   '1A2B3C4D5E', 'yes', 'Some Guy', 'Y', 
   'Test Remarks!', 'new', '1A2A3A4A5A' 'Someone Else',
    TO_DATE('02/14/2014 08:52:44', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 123, TO_DATE('02/14/2015 08:52:44', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS'), 321, 'Y');
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you forgot a comma.

Change

```
'Test Remarks!', 'new', '1A2A3A4A5A' 'Someone Else',
```

to

```
'Test Remarks!', 'new', '1A2A3A4A5A', 'Someone Else',
```

Comment: wow, a second pair of eyes, really helps. I'll select mark your answer as correct as soon as I am able to. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is a silly typo. In my opinion you are missing a `,` between `'1A2A3A4A5A'` and `'Someone Else'` in the 9th line of your code.

Answer (score 2):

you have 18 columns names in one hand and 17 values in other hand.
because you forgot a comma between
'1A2A3A4A5A' and 'Someone Else'